# What are possible trading items of an android town?

Tags: artificial-intelligence, trade

Out in the ruins of Fresno, CA, in the CyboTek factory, there is a group of 260 androids from before the war. They are all mostly household domestic androids, but a few, about 20, are manufacturer plant androids. And, they have one leader, or more of an overseer. A CyboTek calculatron mini-supercomputer,

They are sentient by design, and the latter were hacked and given AI matrix’s, which make them self aware. The live in a robotic community and prefer to stay isolationist, but, they need to trade with outsiders for a vital resource.

Fuel.

They need fusion batteries to stay online. Each domestic robot needs two batteries,  each manufacturer needs six, and the supercomputer needs only one(as he doesn’t need to move around or anything, just calculate) Both types need replacements every 5 years. Also, they need scavenged metal and hardware for repairs.

My question is: what could they trade to get these items?

Comment: What materials and facilities do they have to get/make goods? Also, who are they trading with?

Comment: @Bellerophon: Well, not much. They live in the factory, there is some scrap metal and that is about it. The domestic androids can do pretty much anything a human can, but the Manufacturer androids are designed mostly for heavy lifting and handling factory equipment. They’ll trade with anyone who has the stuff they want, whether it be a slaver or cannibal. They don’t care

Comment: This depends more on the local resources than the androids, farmland, timber, minerals, and means of production will have a bigger impact than android vs human.

Comment: "*what could they trade to get these items?*" This really sounds like you're asking us to fill in your plot hole.

Comment: &RonJohn: No it doesn’t

Comment: #1 What humans live near the CyboTek factory?  #2 What is the human's technology level?  #3 What resources do the humans have?

Comment: #1: 15 miles away their is a agricultural settlement called ReyDel, mostly farmers and sheep herders #2: The equivalent time period I could compare their technology to is the 1680s, but with some advanced weaponry and knowledge of basic medicine #3 They have crops like maize and beans, fresh water, clothing, and houses. Luxury items are rare and only for the richest of people.

Comment: Well, it is [Fresno](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fresno_(miniseries)), after all; they could trade raisins.

Comment: @Spencer: Raisins aren’t valuable. Everyone they trade with is living near Fresno, the all have raisins

Comment: @RonJohn It's not a plot hole, it's more of filling a gap in the worldbuilding.

Comment: @a4amdroid: See this guy gets it. Him being an android and all

Comment: To VTCers... "Too broad" means "the answer would require a book-length treatise to do justice to the question."  Please explain how this question is too broad.

Comment: Where do farmers and shepherds get fusion batteries?

Comment: @a4android gaps can be small, and gaps can be big.

Comment: @RonJohn Size isn't everything. It's conceptual & cognitive capacity needed to fill it. Some small gaps take huge amounts of brainpower to fix, while some large gaps can be plugged with one or two good ideas. The usual horses for courses dictum applies.

Answer (score 4):

**The Oldest Profession**

Androids don't get tired, they don't get sick, and they don't get traumatized and can feel emotions selectively, most of all they can calculate and catalog values with zero errors and never forget what they are owed.

This means they are the ultimate pimps, ever been bitch-slapped by a titanium-boned hand? yeah. You're not gonna be skimming from SN-142675-A3's cut of the take ever again are ya ho? These androids operate brothels full of human "merchandise" where they obtain items that are valuable to meat-bags which they can then trade for things that are valuable to themselves. It also lets them feel superior to the fleshy meat-puppets that used to utilize them as "domestic" servants once too.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is less "what could androids trade" and more "what do non-androids (I'm assuming humans) need?"  Assuming these androids have superior strength, or at least superior stamina, they could spend time tilling soil and farming crops to trade to humans for specified parts. Farming is stupidly hard work without dedicated equipment, and would be made doubly difficult by massive environmental collapse.

Both models of androids would be able to work around the clock and ignore issues like sunstroke or exhaustion. You could say the domestic models could effectively raise animals. After all, they would understand nutrition and animal behavior (lots of families have pets). As for the manufacture models, they would be tractors, trailers, forklifts, and digging machines all at the same time.

Plus, if you wanted, you could say they have enough pre-apocalypse knowledge to build breweries, which is the trade good to end all trade goods. Other than making wasteland life worth living, booze could prevent infections and purify stagnant water. It also doesn't soil quickly, so the androids could make a stockpile until humans visited. Making them smarter than humans could open a can of worms, though. Eh, they could figure out fermentation through trail and error. Either way, alcohol would be a great thing for them to manufacture and trade.

Right now this community is in a bad place, economically speaking. The resource they need seems to be finite, as no one can manufacture new fusion batteries. A huge portion of there time might be spent looking from new stockpiles or scavenging ruins. If they aren't nomadic, they would probably put the word out they want those fusion batteries so humans can look for them. Just one could be worth a whole cow to a android. Its a situation that humans could easily exploit unless androids are proactive. "You can trade those two Fusion batteries for eight barrels of water, but if you go any higher they might just shoot you and take them for nothing. They know people will still trade with them if they do. The payout is worth it."

If I were on team android (go electric sheep!), I would spend a lot of time trying to get a fusion battery manufacturing machine working again. Until I do that, my entire people are just living on borrowed time. That or trying to convert to other forms of batteries. Living with a power-cord plugged into a twenty pound lithium battery would be a pain, but at least I'd still be alive.

Got to make sure I can defend my homeland, too. I have a lot of nice trade goods, a finite number of allies, and need a lot of time and effort to repair myself if I get injured. Humans might decide to litter my fields with landmines or take potshots with long ranged rifles. Doesn't matter how durable I am, they can wear me down. Isolationism (like you said) and a zero-tolerance policy to weapons that are capable of hurting me would be ideal.

This is a really fun situation you cooked up.

Comment: Yes I know, and thank you. They do eventually get a fusion battery factory working, with the help of my main character. And they also get a android producing factory workin too, and when it cuts to a few decades after my main character dies, we see that the androids have become a mighty nation. There supposed to be Marxist communist, who share all their batteries based on need, it really is a fun scenario to write

Comment: Also, they leader of then communtiy, the supercomputer, is under a lot of stress. Fusion battery sellers are starting to drive up their prices as they know the androids need them.

Comment: Cool to see you and I were on similar wavelengths, and sorry to make you read a bunch of stuff you already know. Is the Marxist angel why you have differing amounts of batteries per android? Cause that is an interesting plot point.

Comment: @Pinnion Minion: Yeah, it is. The supercomputers laws dictate that each android only get as many batteries they need for the bare minimum to stay alive. I really wanted to show a Marxist government in action, and robots, who have no corruption of greed seemed perfect for that

Comment: @Talos5 I could argue the point about robot greed, but you do have the benefit of a un-supplied robot being offline until their powered. An un-supplied human is just dead.

Comment: Yeah, and the supercomputer has like an internet connection with the androids, like a robotic hive mind. There is a really sad part at the end of the book though. About 400 years after the finally got their fusion battery factory running, they were all destroyed by a lunatic with an EMP emitter, and their CyboTek factory was destroyed

Comment: Dang, that is sad. Not that its my place, but I think that hive mind plot point might take emotion away from the story. Having the super-comp actually convince the androids to remain in the community, rely on trade instead or brute force, and surrender their batteries for the greater good would be more meaningful then simply sending out orders.

Comment: No, he still has to convince them to stay. It’s not all the way like a hive mind, it’s just like their all interconnected. Like an internet. Each robots still 100% sentient and is capable of leaving if he wishes. Most just don’t because they are safer their

Answer (score 1):

**Your androids are living in a factory...**

A factory designed to produce a very wide variety of parts and components of all shapes and sizes.  That means it could be used to build the one thing survivors won't have easy access to:

*Heavy equipment*

You see, shovels are easy to find after any apocalypse<sup>1</sup>, just start moving the bricks away from your local WalMart or hardware store and take all the shovels you need.  But eventually you need to move an appreciable amount of dirt in a reasonable amount of time.  And for that you really need a [D9 Cat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caterpillar_D9).

Now, any half-way decent apocalypse would have ruined the delicate and remarkably extensive web of business supply routes needed to keep a heavy equipment manufacturing plant running.  But your androids have the solution: and best of all, *they don't need trained operators* because your androids control a factory that builds artificial brains.

Best of all, most of the raw material your factory needs (if not all) is supplied from the ruins of Fresno itself: a nearly never-ending supply of metals and chemicals of all kinds.

**Assumptions**

- The factory is self-sustaining.  It doesn't depend on receiving sub-components manufactured elsewhere.  It only needs raw materials.
- The factory is entirely operable.

---

<sub><sup>1</sup> *You didn't mention the conditions of the world, but you did say Fresno was in ruins.  I'm jumping to the traditional and reliable standby for these situations, the good ol' apolcalypse.  You can never go wrong with an apocalypse.*</sub>

Comment: The humans don’t manufacture the Fusiln batteries they scavenge them. There is a limited supply

Comment: What is limiting the androids that they cannot scavange them?  Or is it simply an issue of percentages?  They can't scavange enough without the human's help?

Comment: There are only 260 of them. And the need 700 batteriesevery 5 years, so they need human help

Answer (score 1):

**Civilization**

The androids have no time to spare with humans and their silly conflicts for resources on this wasteland, so they will want not only to have their precious fusion batteries, but also rush human civilization back to a place were it wouldn't be wanting to kill each other for water and food.

The first product the androis will want to offer is medical care, all those household androids will probably be proficient in first-aid and with some luck they will be able to put online a few real robo-docs to offer proper medical care.

The survivores will be able to scavenge the ruins for the batteries, and knowing that its the lives of their loved ones on the line will make sure they are eager to trade.

Right, so now the androids have preserved the life of many people and probably saved a lot of knowledge from the past on the process.

Next comes Agriculture.

Everyone loves tales of badass survivors swinging katanas around, but the real heroes of the Wasteland will be those capable of producing food. Here the Androids will have the upper hand, they will be able to till the land and make a variety of tests to make sure the plants will grow healthy.

Now that the survivors have food, comes civilization.

Now the androids will be printing books and setting up energy grids for the human settlements, using their knowledge to make sure the humans won't be dwelling in their own filthy for the next hundred of years.

So, why bother with helping the humans at all?

Simply, the androids really don't want the humans to start thinking that maybe the Romans had the right idea and that all technology should be banned, or maybe that all technology should be controlled by some feudalist dudes in power armor.

Answer (score 0):

**Medicine.** If your humans are 1680s technology the androids can trade them all sorts of medical technology (and medical know how) which the humans can't make themselves. Proper dosages, proper quality control, proper chemistry and biochemistry - it'll be much better than anything the humans can make.

1. Antibiotics.
2. Painkillers - everything from asprin (you need a chemistry lab to turn willow bark into a decent painkiller) to opioids.
3. Contraceptive implants or pills.
4. Vaccines.

If they can put most of these in disposable one-use syrettes, then the humans have to keep trading for more.

Also...

- Anaesthesia. Your robots can become surgeons and anaesthetists. The locals are sawing off gangrenous legs with no anaesthetic and hauling teeth out with pliers after getting the patient dread drunk, and they can't remove a burst appendix or operate on a heart bypass or a brain tumour. Your guys can corner the market. Perhaps the people have to come to them. Perhaps they have a mobile hospital.
- Prosthetic limbs. Perhaps even bionic/cybernetic ones?

**Agricultural stuff.**

- Pesticides and herbicides (weed killer)
- Nitrate and phosphate based fertiliser
- Mass produced ploughs and tractors to pull them. Combine harvesters. Basically all sorts of machinery which reduces the number of people, horses and oxen required to plant, weed or get in the harvest.

Answer (score 0):

To get a feel for this you may want to play the Fallout series video games which take place 200 years after an all out nuclear war.  It gives you a general sense what living in the aftermath of civilization is like.  They did have 1 similar situation where humans and robots teamed up to mass produce guns, and sell them.

1. Knowledge

You give the robot a blank storage device(book,sheets of paper, or etc), and they fill it with information you need.  You can do this infinitely with no restocking.

2. Training on any subject they have access to skill tapes
   Training: How do I build X, how do I farm, or any topic 
    Minimal amount of scrap needed which you can probably reuse.
3. Labor:  They perform some task for you.
4. Manufacturing:  Stipulation the person has to bring all the pieces, and the robots assemble or construct it.  Maybe they bring in scrap metal, and melt it down, and forge something.  The fee paid goes to wear and tear, and new batteries, and/or a charging station.  The customer gets something produced in minutes/hours that they couldn't do in a timely fashion.

Additional thoughts:

```
  20 robots need 6x batteries = 120
 239 need 2                   = 478
   1 main computer            =   1
-------------------------------------
                                 599 batteries / 5 years
```

1825 days/ 599 batteries = 1 battery approx every 3 days to stay viable.

If you want to survive you will need to recharge the batteries.  Even car batteries are rechargeable so the robots will also have to be.  That way when a battery can no longer be recycled they can be scrapped for parts or raw materials.

Additional problem,  people will scavenge the fusion batteries closet to the factory first, and they spread out.  As the humans spread out it will take longer and longer for them to return with the batteries, and they will be at increased risk of being attacked,killed, robbed, or etc.

The other thing that work pretty well is if they can build a utility company.  Say you build a dam, you can purify and sell the water.  They could produce electricity, say either solar or put a water wheel in a river.  I chose these as they are relatively low maintenance.  Wind mills, and actual generators are much higher maintenance.

The biggest problem I see hear is the **isolation**, part of the robots plan.
It is highly advantageous for them to become part of a town, or produce a new class of robot that fulfills this need.  I suggest coming up with a compromise in the form of a contract with the neighboring humans.  You won't build closer than 2000ft or whatever to the robots.

The basic needs of humans is food and shelter, without that you will have no one to gather your supplies.  Many will become raiders and kill or rob others.  Only a few will survive, and they may eventually come, and try to raid you.  Pretty soon you won't have enough people left who knows what a fusion battery looks like.  You will not have a reliable supply of trustworthy humans.  They won't truly value learning or anything beyond their next meal and shelter.  Also they won't have kids so humans will eventually die out.

However, if a town forms, you will be able to fill a range of needs.  Including teacher robots, who train the kids.  The robots can barter protection from the town.  If you can produce electricity or purified water for said town you got it made.

As the town advances, the robots can produce medicines and scientific research to increase their value.  It will be many decades before enough spare people exist to have specialist in each field, and when it does happen they will need teachers to teach them.

Potentially farms fields/green houses but they will need to start making new robots to fill their ever expanding roles.

The town will automatically start advancing technologically, and the robots can kick start them with their knowledge, for a fee of course.  Pretty soon the town will have a well armed police(protection) force, and they will be able to easily kill of any raiders that come calling.

The robots need for **fuel** usually means a highly processed, and refine substance that needs advanced technology to produce.  The town could start mass producing for you.  You would have a symbiotic relationship good for both parties.

The humans will reproduce, and the town will slowly expand and the humans will go out in numbers looking for supplies bring back fusion batteries,fuel, and etc with the other supplies they find.

Also if the robots are being protected by the town, they need less robots back at home base and more out in the field doing work that earns them the supplies they need.  The robots on guard duty are a liability as they produce no tangible goods,  but still cost ## batteries, and ## gallons of fuel.

Answer (score 0):

They could manufacture agricultural items such as plows and digging tools. It does not need fuel to work which they need. They can do repairs as well. Basically fulfilling the roles of blacksmiths. This of course depends on the overall technological capabilities of the surrounding communities that trade with them. They can also do assembly of machinery given the specs are available or in the overseer's memory/database.

Additionally they can trade information in manufacturing and calculations as well such as how deep to dig a well given certain parameters etc. This could prove more valuable than tools.